# How to add a "#!" before all the urls for ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I'm doing an Ajax site and I must add to all urls "#!" house (does not work for external urls) from my site when a visitor clicks on the url.
For example when someone clicks on a url http://mysiteajax.com/contact/ ", the script changes the url like this:" http://mysiteajax.com/#!/contact / "

I have coded a little script jQuery but it does not work:

```
   <script>
        var  base_url = "http://localhost/ajaxsite/";
        function link(href) {

        // Check if the URL is an internal url
        if(href.indexOf(base_url) !=-1 || href.indexOf('http://') == -1 || href.indexOf('https://') == -1) {
        href = href.replace(base_url,'');
        return base_url + '#!/' + href;
         }
        }

        // Changes the link when someone clicks
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function() {
        $('a').attr('href', link(this));
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: *"it does not work"*: **How** does it not work? What happens and what you expect to happen?

Comment: Why #!? # is a fragment marker, so your request won't go to the path specified...

Comment: @tjamson: [AJAX crawling: Guide for webmasters and developers](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=174992). I assume he reads the value of the fragment identifier and makes the request to that path (like so many other web pages too :)).

Comment: @Felix King - My point was that `http://mysiteajax.com/` will be called, not  `http://mysiteajax.com/contact/`. Anything after the # is not passed to the server.

Comment: Be careful using hashbangs. http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs I'd suggest using the history api and skip this hashbang as much as possible.

Comment: @tjameson Not unless a Javascript runs that captures that link and performs an Ajax request on the full url without the hashbang. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol - I sure hope not, that would make me cry. It would also possibly make the browser cry. Don't do this unless you want to see digital tears.

Comment: I won't. I rather make my site work without Javascript at all, and then add some of this trickery to make it work with Ajax. The only reason to use the hash is to reflect the current state of the page in the url. You could use a hashbang to allow Google to index these pages, but if you use regular urls, the site is crawled normally and you won't need this.

Comment: You only need this when someone in a browser that doesn't support history api is clicking around on you Ajax enhanced site, copies an url to a specific state, and pastes it on a forum or so. If you want *that* url to be indexed properly too, you need the hashbang. Not really important, usually. Users of those browsers won't know how to copy/paste. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some problems that I see:

- There is no ajax in the code snippet
- You are passing an anchor-tag element to link(), not an href
- This will have no effect on page crawlers because crawlers don't execute JS
- The # and anything after it will not be passed to your server

If I assume that you have ajax somewhere, then this will still not work for reasons 2 and 3 (assuming that your ajax request should be made to the root)

Change this:

```
$('a').attr('href', link(this));
```

to this:

```
$(this).attr('href', link($(this).attr('href')));
```

This is a little messy, but it's the only way to only change the clicked element using only jQuery-isms.

I don't see any reason to doing it the way you are doing it. If you're looking for [this](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=174992), I don't think Google's web crawlers interpret JS (that would take way too long on the scale they do their crawling). You'll need to put this in the HTML itself.

Comment: Yes I have another script to call the page with Ajax.
Now the code works fine but when I click on the link several times and it multiplies in the address bar, do you have an idea how I to solve this problem.

Comment: Uh, only call it once? I would just call this at page load instead of on click.